# Ajax response in struts2 action class

Tags: ajax, jsp, struts2

I am trying to implement ajax in jsp(avoid form submit) using struts2. I used ajax code to pass request via url to struts2 action. But the response from struts2 is not get populated in jap. Its showing "null" value. My code to call a action in jsp using AJAX is as Follows.

```
    function ajaxEditFunctionCall(){  
 var xmlHttp;
     var url = "ajaxcall.action?stateName="+frm.stateName.value;  
  try{   
    xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();   
  }catch (e){
      try{ 
      xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); 
      }catch (e){ 
          try{  
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
            }catch (e){
                alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
                return false;
            }
      }
  }
  alert(1);
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = showMessage; 
      alert(2);

  xmlHttp.open("GET", URL, true); 

       alert(3);
       xmlHttp.send(null);  
  }

      function showMessage() { 
       alert("Inside Show Message1");
         alert(xmlhttp.readyState);
             if(xmlhttp.readyState==4)  
            { 
             alert("Inside Show Message2&ReadyState4");
                 alert(xmlhttp.responseText);  
            }  
       }  

   Included following code in Action Class:

public String ajaxcall() throws Exception{

     System.out.println("Inside AjaxCall");
     String errorXml = "This is a Sample to Check";  

     response.setContentType("text/html"); 
     response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache"); 
         response.setContentType("text/html");   
     response.getWriter().write(errorXml); 

     return null;

}
```

Code included in Struts.xml:

```
  <action name="ajaxcall" class="com.logic.action.CustomerAction" method="ajaxcall">
       <result name="success" >/pages/customer/addCustomer.jsp</result> 
   </action>
```

I think the error is in the action class-response statement and in struts.xml. Can any one please help me to fix this issue. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why would you use "raw" JavaScript when so many better JS options exist? In any case, it's easy to check what's coming back in the response using Firebug/Chrome dev tools/etc, if the response is valid, then it's in your JS.

Comment: i believe that a simple debugger will help you to pinpoint the issue.what if you submit the form is it working perfectly ?

Comment: @Umesh When i click on submit button it calls the javascript and control goes to specified action class and print static message in log file. But the response is not coming in jsp<responseText>. What i used in action class is right or wrong?

Comment: @Dave Newton: I dont know other Javascript to use ajax. It's working fine in Struts1 so i used to try it in struts2. If anyother way is avl to do this please help me.

Comment: @shiva: what is this response in your method.i believe either you can use stream result to sent data or if you want to sent a chunk of HTML from your action class just send back the template itself.

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi: My response in this program is a string,stored in errorXml>local variable. How to pass it to my jsp? can u please tell in depth about this with sample code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, the correction needs to be done to the JavaScript function. When you say `var xmlHttp`, it has a scope inside the function `ajaxEditFunctionCall` and not for the `showMessage`. Also, `xmlhttp` in `showMessage()` is not same as `xmlHttp` object in `ajaxEditFunctionCall`. So, keep the `var xmlHttp` declaration global and make the corrections. Here is the working code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            var xmlHttp;
            function ajaxEditFunctionCall(){

                var URL = "ajaxcall.action?stateName=State1";
                try{
                    xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }catch (e){
                    try{
                        xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                    }catch (e){
                        try{
                            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                        }catch (e){
                            alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                //alert(1);
                xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = showMessage;
                //alert(2);

                xmlHttp.open("GET", URL, true);

                //alert(3);
                xmlHttp.send(null);
            }

            function showMessage() {
                //alert("Inside Show Message1");
                //alert(xmlHttp.readyState);
                if(xmlHttp.readyState==4)
                {
                    alert("Inside Show Message2&ReadyState4");
                    alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
                }
            }  
        </script>
```

The Java code is:

```
public class CustomerAction extends ActionSupport implements ServletResponseAware {

    HttpServletResponse response;

    public String ajaxcall() {

        System.out.println("Inside AjaxCall");
        String errorXml = "This is a Sample to Check";

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        try {
            response.getWriter().write(errorXml);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void setServletResponse(HttpServletResponse response) {
        this.response = response;
    }
}
```

The struts.xml is:

```
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="ajaxcall" class="com.logic.action.CustomerAction" method="ajaxcall">
            <result name="success" >/pages/customer/addCustomer.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

Comment: Thanks for your brief Example. While i trying this correction and run my application. It shows the Ajax>>readystate as 0,1,2,3,4 perfectly. But the responseText is showing as "/no action mapped for name space / and action name in alert box. Where i have to check. I have specified the action name in struts.xml file. I think now the problem is in the URL.

Comment: I am getting the Alert message as no action mapping found in JSP. Can u help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Check if the url which you try to pass from JavaScript matches with the struts.xml configuration.

Comment: I find the error. I have specified same action name for two classes in struts.xml file. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 6):

I believe this simple code should work for Ajax calling.The example below is using stream result but you can use even JSON,XML or any other format you want as return.
As a server-side struts2 did not take in to account if request is coming from script/ajax or any other way

### Action

```
public class TextResult extends ActionSupport  {
    private InputStream inputStream;
    public InputStream getInputStream() {
        return inputStream;
    }

    public String execute() throws Exception {
        inputStream = new StringBufferInputStream("Hello World! This is a text string response from a Struts 2 Action.");
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Struts.xml file

### struts.xml

```
<action name="text-result" class="actions.TextResult">
    <result type="stream">
        <param name="contentType">text/html</param>
        <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

you can use above setup with your JS. On successful calling Action will return *"Hello World! This is a text string response from a Struts 2 Action."*  string

### **Update**

Here is a complete working code as an Ajax call

### JSP Code

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
            var xmlHttp;
            function ajaxEditFunctionCall(){

                var URL = "welcomeAjax.action?stateName=State1";
                try{
                    xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }catch (e){
                    try{
                        xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                    }catch (e){
                        try{
                            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                        }catch (e){
                            alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                //alert(1);
                xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = showMessage;
                //alert(2);

                xmlHttp.open("GET", URL, true);

                //alert(3);
                xmlHttp.send(null);
            }

            function showMessage() {
                //alert("Inside Show Message1");
                //alert(xmlHttp.readyState);
                if(xmlHttp.readyState==4)
                {
                    alert("Inside Show Message2&ReadyState4");
                    alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
                }
            }  
        </script>
</head>
<body>
<s:form id="form">
<input type="button" onclick="ajaxEditFunctionCall()"/>
</s:form>
<body>
```

Here is the code from Action class

### Action

```
private InputStream inputStream;
    public InputStream getInputStream() {
        return inputStream;
    }

    public String ajax() throws Exception {
        inputStream = new StringBufferInputStream("Hello World! This is a text string response from a Struts 2 Action.");
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

Finally we need to define the relation in struts.xml file

### struts.xml

```
<action name="welcomeAjax" class="com.demo.WelcomeAction" method="ajax">
            <result type="stream">
                <param name="contentType">text/html</param>
                <param name="inputName">inputStream</param>
            </result>
 </action>
```

the above code is working perfectly fine and hope will help you.

Comment: What about the Jsp code? Can u post that too? If u do that i can check it easily. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @shiva have you seen the post by `James Jithin`, i believe he has already pointed out various problems in your code

Comment: Struts2 supports Ajax or not?

Comment: Struts2 does not care if you using ajax calling or simple calling.and it worked perfectly with any Java-Script framework.

Comment: Thank u so much Umesh. But the above program itself doesn't display the responseText in jsp page. It shows a alert with html heading is:Struts Problem Report,No action mapped for namespace/ and action name[object MozURLProperty]. I dont know to find this issue. Please help me.

Comment: @shiva i have added a working code in the above post,you can check and try that

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got the output in xml and also in text format.Your code helped me a lot find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

above example is perfectly working

to convert into json object use

```
jsonobj=jQuery.parseJSON(req.responseText);
```