# Struts2 - Using jquery ajax to load info from database

Tags: ajax, hibernate, jquery, struts2

for developing my webApp I m using `struts 2 hibernate 3` and I want to run a query when I change the values ​​in `<s:select/>` tag and pass the result of this query in a hidden input
and i want to stay in the same page when changed element of select tag

my page jsp loot like this example :

```
<form  name="evalform" action="saveOrUpdateSousEval"    method="post"  >    
<s:iterator begin="1" end="4" status="status">
        <s:hidden   name="SousEval_Note"   
                value="99" 
                placeholder="entrer  Note"
                      />
        <s:select 
            headerValue="---------------- Select ---------------"
            headerKey="-1" 
            list="SousItemsListGrille"
            listKey="SousItem_ID"   
            listValue="SousItem_Libelle"
            name="sousEvalItem.SousItem_ID"  
            cssClass="selectedId"

            />

</s:iterator>   
</form>
```

here I have start by getting id of element selected  :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#idselectdiv .selectedId").change(function () {
        var idd = $(this).val(); 
//each element selected in each select tag  has an id and i want excute query of this id  
        alert(" id selected "+idd);
        $.ajax({
        //somthing here !!
    });
    });
    </script>
```

in struts. xmli define this action :

```
<action name="ponderation" method="getItembyPonderation"        class="action.classAction">
    <result name="success"    >/oki.jsp</result>
 </action>
```

in my class Action  i have this methode :

```
public Double getItembyPonderation(){
System.out.print("enter getItembyPonderation ok");
Double b = null;
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) ActionContext.getContext().get(ServletActionContext.HTTP_REQUEST);
List<Double> a=selectponder.selectponderation(Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("SousItem_ID")));
        while (a != null) {
        return  b=a.get(0);
        }
return b;
}
```

in my classDao :

```
public List<Double> selectponderation(Long idsousitem){
    List<Double> valponderation = null;
    try {
    valponderation = session.createQuery("SELECT a.ponderation FROM items a, sousitems b WHERE a.Item_ID = b.Item_ID and b.SousItem_ID="+idsousitem).list();                                                                    ;
} catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
return valponderation;
}
```

here  i needan idea to do that

Comment: Please tell me what is the exact problem? I am not getting.

Comment: @Aniket I think the problem is in calling ajax but the action should return `oki.jsp`.

Comment: the problem is i don't know how to do for load result of query and  put it in a hidden input and stay in the same ok.jsp  because i have many  tag select

Comment: [Is this what are you looking for?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8936901/1031945)

Comment: @Aniket Yes somthing lik that  but I just found a others  solution  I'm happy for your support  problem solved wow

Comment: possible duplicate of [dynamically change attribute id input jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871011/dynamically-change-attribute-id-input-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#idselectdiv .selectedId").change(function () {
        var idd = $(this).val(); 
//each element selected in each select tag  has an id and i want excute query of this id  
        alert(" id selected "+idd);
$.ajax({
        url : 'your_action name_where_you_execute_query',
        data:{
            idd:idd
        },
        type : 'GET',
        dataType : 'as_you_want_from_your_action'

    });
 });
    </script>
```

Above is example of how you can calll an action and pass your parameter to that action.
Do you get it?

Comment: If you are satisfied then can you mark this answer as verified?

Comment: Accepting Answers: How does it work?

Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved.
You may select any answer on questions you asked as the "accepted" answer. Only one answer at a time can be the 'accepted' answer.
There's a brief period (15 minutes) immediately after asking the question when you can't accept an answer.
To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green.