# dynamically change attribute id input jquery

Tags: jquery, jsp

Here I want to  affect a value to  dynamically  attribute id of input
 here my code jQuery : for this code I can change to 0 the first value of input as `id=ouseval_0__SousEval_Note` but  I have many input with dynamic id

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#idselectdiv .tdLabelwidht").change(function () {
    var idd = $(this).val();
    alert(" selected value@ ="+idd);
    if(idd=="-1"){
        alert(" Veuillez selectionner un bon choix ");  
            }
    if($(this).find("option:selected").text()!="Conforme"){
        $("#souseval_5__SousEval_Note").val(0);         
    }
    alert(" selected option- "+$(this).find("option:selected").text());

    });
</script>
```

in my JSP  I have a slect tag and the input who I want edit here value  if  user select an option of select tag different of conform:

```
<s:set name="n" value="0"/>
<s:iterator value="item"  status="idStatus"  >
<s:select
        label="%{Item_Libelle}"  
        headerValue="---------------- Select ---------------"
        headerKey="-1"
        list="sousitem"
        listKey="SousItem_ID"   
        listValue="SousItem_Libelle"
        cssClass="tdLabelwidht" 
        id="selectedId"
        name="%{'souseval['+#n+'].sousEvalItem.SousItem_ID'}"  
/>  
<s:textfield    name="%{'souseval['+#n+'].SousEval_Note'}"      
        value="%{ponderation}"    
                placeholder="entrer  Note"
/>
<s:set name="n" value="%{#n+1}"/>   
</s:iterator>
```

equivalent  code HTML :

```
<tr>
<td class="tdLabel"></td>
<td>
<input id="souseval_5__SousEval_Note" type="text" placeholder="entrer Note" value="10" name="souseval[5].SousEval_Note">
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Are you just asking how to use a variable in a selector?  Like this?:  `$('#souseval_' + someVariable + '__SousEval_Note')`

Comment: Yes  in my script jquery  i have `$("#souseval_5__SousEval_Note").val(0); ` and  i want to replac 5 with variable according ['+#n+'] in my jsp

Comment: possible duplicate of [Struts2 - Using jquery ajax to load info from database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18846101/struts2-using-jquery-ajax-to-load-info-from-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely familiar with JSP, but as a server-side language it must have some way to simply echo a literal value to the client-side output.  This commonly happens throughout server-side code.  For example, if you have some raw HTML in your markup and you just need to put some text within it.

That same mechanism for echoing a raw value to the output can be used to echo JavaScript code as well.  From the server-side code's perspective, there's really no difference between HTML and JavaScript.  It's just output being rendered to the page.  It's only on the client-side that it becomes significant.

So let's say you have JavaScript like this:

```
$('#souseval_5__SousEval_Note').val(0);
```

Now let's say you want the `5` to be dynamic, based on a variable.  Since this is JavaScript code, it would need to be a client-side JavaScript variable:

```
$('#souseval_' + someVariable + '__SousEval_Note').val(0);
```

But since we're talking about *server-side* variables, those variables can emit client-side constants.  So the client-side code can end up looking like this:

```
$('#souseval_' + '5' + '__SousEval_Note').val(0);
```

So let's say, for example, you want 5 of these:

```
$('#souseval_' + '1' + '__SousEval_Note').val(0);
$('#souseval_' + '2' + '__SousEval_Note').val(0);
$('#souseval_' + '3' + '__SousEval_Note').val(0);
$('#souseval_' + '4' + '__SousEval_Note').val(0);
$('#souseval_' + '5' + '__SousEval_Note').val(0);
```

And you want these to be built in a loop based on some server-side collection.  Again, I'm not familiar with JSP, but in pseudo-code it might look something like this:

```
<% for(int i = 0; i < someCollection.Length; i++) { %>
    $('#souseval_' + '<% i %>' + '__SousEval_Note').val(0);
<% } %>
```

Essentially what this is doing it looping through a server-side collection to emit multiple lines of client-side code.  This would create the 5 lines above.  So on the client-side it's not looping, it's just running multiple statements.  But the code being maintained, the server-side code, is using a loop based on the collection.

Comment: I don't need to define  someCollection  in my jsp i have  a global variabl and each iterate of iterator this varial increment . so i want somthing like that `$('#souseval_' + '['+#n+']' + '__SousEval_Note').val(0);`  and keep the some varibale n  in iterator

Comment: @boyka: However you perform the iteration server-side is up to you.  The concept is the same, though.  You just echo the output in a loop.

Comment: did you now  How to pass JSTL value to jquery variable ?because i m traying to use your method but i have my variabl in `<s:set name="n" value="%{#n+1}"/>` and this variabl i want pass it to jquery  somthing like that `var nn= "${n}";`